# Remove DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

What i need is to remove the DOM element with the help of jQuery or javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
  });
});
```

I tried `hide()` and `show()` which would just alter the CSS to display that element. However, what I need is to disable that particular element from DOM and again get that element back when clicked on `show`.

Comment: If you completely remove it, how are you going to show it? Why do you need to completely remove it if you're just going to re-show it?

Comment: @KevinB I want to hide it from DOM so that I could apply some validation to it.

Comment: What validation would you be applying to a p element?

Comment: just add a class to the inputs that must be validated and remove it to the elements which don't need to be vlaidated anymore

Comment: Or, you know, use the fact that it's hidden rather than a class.

Comment: @KevinB the code above is just an example, to hide <p> from DOM

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-removal/

Comment: You're asking about what you assume is the solution to your  problem instead about describing in full the actual problem.

Comment: ...there's *no* indication in your question of why `.hide()` and `.show()` are insufficient. Again, you're not asking about what the actual problem is. Read: [What is the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `detach()` method instead.

[`detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

Comment: How about putting them back?

Comment: The documentation can't know where the elements were when you removed them. This suffers from the same problem described in the question when using `.remove()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p> Hide and show this element <p>    
<button id="button">Hide/Show</button>
<script>

    var p; //sets a variable p
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
      if ( p ) { //checks if p is empty
        p.appendTo( "body" ); //if p is not empty, appends it to the body
        p = null; //sets p to NULL
      } else {
        p = $( "p" ).detach(); //stored the detached element to p
      }
    });
    </script>
```

This is the solution I was looking for. With the help from @Brad M , and jQuery Documentation, I got it solved.